# How to optimize matrix multiplication on itself transposed using CUDA?

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I have a matrix (M) of floats, roughly 17000 by 10000 values. I need to get scalar multiplications of each row by each row (so 17000 by 17000 values), which can be alternatively formalized as multiplying M by the transposed M.

I am new to CUDA, so I can write a "naive" solution using a thread for every matrix element but it's probably suboptimal computation speed-wise.

Alternatively, I can use something like `cublasSgemm(...)` with M *and* the transposed M as arguments, but the transposing is an additional operation that should not be necessary, and the additional memory usage is also considerable (I have only a 4 GB video card freely available).

Please help me with the optimal (or at least better) solution.

If it's important, I do know the number of columns beforehand (literally using `#define numCol 10001`), but the number of rows can vary as the rows are parsed from multiple .csv files.

Comment: When using `cublasSgemm` (or any other BLAS implementation) you can specify each input matrix to be transposed on the fly (`CUBLAS_OP_T`), just take another look at the [API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm). Due to how matrix multiplication is implemented (partitioning), I don't think you will be able to get more performance than the CUBLAS implementation. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/matrixMul/matrixMul.cu) CUDA sample to see a basic implementation with a lot of comments for explanation.

Comment: By using `CUBLAS_OP_T` you also wont need more memory than with a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a symmetric rank update. There is a family of functions specifically for this, e.g. `cublasSsyrk` for floats.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-syrk

Note that those only update the lower or upper triangular matrix as the other half is redundant